# It is good practice to pass the dbcontext to a function?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

it is a good practice to do this?

in Controller action

```
ValidateSomEntity(icontext, someid)
icontext.SaveChanges();

public ValidateSomEntity(IContext db_, int someid)
{
    db_.SomEntity.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == someid);
   // do validate
}
```

or is better to do this
in Controller action

```
ValidateSomEntity(someid)
    icontext.SaveChanges();

    public ValidateSomEntity(int someid)
    {
        usgin(var db_ = new SomeDbContext())
       {
          db_.SomEntity.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == someid);
            //do validate
       }
    }
```

my problem will be that Icontext is a interface of the dbContext and in the controller is built by ninject so i don't know if it will be a problem when I create a unit test for the function or the controller

Answer (score 0):

If you use IOC container, the recommended approach is to inject the IContext in your contoller constructor per Http Request, then you can use it in any function. I would not recommend passing the context into your function.

Comment: yes I do that, and how I can when I test the application with unit test pass the fake context to the function? Iam not understand how can achieve that